# Deleted public_html without reason

Tags: centos, files, web

I had a problem today in the morning which I am still trying to figure it out, so it does not happen again.

Somehow a lot of files from public_html got deleted, except one folder. I did not delete anything. Basically the whole website went missing.

How can I check logs on what happened to these files?

All I did today was yum update and then upgrade cyberpanel to the newest version, I hope this was not the problem.

Thank you

Comment: Filesystem activities are normally not logged, except if you configure auditing. To limit the amount of audit data, you could audit the `unlink` system call if you are afraid it might happen again. Apart from that, perhaps the application that deleted the files logged something. Search for clues such as known filenames in /var/log and the systemd journal.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will check